# ASP.NET Knockout dependent dropdown list cannot get selected value when postback

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I have a asp.net page with knockout 2.3.0. The page contains a dependent dropdown list. In the example.js it initials these 2 drop down lists. The dependent list is working.

However when I selected value in front end, I cannot get selected value when button clicked in server end. The selected value always set to default value.

Please help!

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="JS/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1" data-bind="options: jobAreas, optionsCaption:'--Job Areas--', optionsText: 'jobAreaName', optionsValue: 'jobAreaID', value: selectedJobArea">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl2" data-bind="options: jobFunctions, optionsCaption:'--Job Function--', optionsText: 'jobFunctionName', optionsValue: 'jobFunctionID', value: selectedJobFunction, enable: jobFunctions().length">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="Test" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptTags" runat="server">
    <script src="JS/example.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

In example.js

```
    function ViewModel(items) {
    this.jobAreas = ko.observableArray(items);
    this.selectedJobArea = ko.observable();
    this.selectedJobFunction = ko.observable();

    function getById(items, value) {
        if(!value) {
            return [];
        }

        var result = ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function(item) {
            return item.jobAreaID === value;
        });

        return result && result.JubfunctionItems || [];
    }

    this.jobFunctions = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = this.jobAreas();
        var id = this.selectedJobArea();
        return getById(items, id);
    }, this);

}

var items = [
    { jobAreaName: 'Ford', jobAreaID: 1, JubfunctionItems:
     [
         { jobFunctionName: 'F-150', jobFunctionID: 1},
         { jobFunctionName: 'F-250', jobFunctionID: 2}
     ]
    },
    { jobAreaName: 'Honda', jobAreaID: 2, JubfunctionItems:
     [
         { jobFunctionName: 'Civic', jobFunctionID: 5},
         { jobFunctionName: 'Accord', jobFunctionID: 6}
     ]
    }
];

var module = {};

module.viewModel = new ViewModel(items);

ko.applyBindings(module.viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdownlist was declared as empty in your aspx page, and will be recorded in the ViewState as such.

Any dropdownlist items generated via javascript won't be recognize as valid items and won't recorded in .SelectedValue

You can, however, access the selected value by accessing the `Request.Form` directly. For example:

`Request.Form[ddl2.UniqueID]`

`Request.Form[ddl1.UniqueID]`

Comment: Thanks Neo. Is that possible to get text rather then id?

Comment: For the text I'm afraid you'll have to get your hands dirty... Create a `<asp:HiddenField>` and use javascript to update its value with the selected dropdown text. Then you can access the HiddenField value from your code-behind

Comment: Thank you again. I found out if I use <asp:HiddenField> I can set value in js and get both ID and value for selected item. Also I can access these value in post back. Just wondering why only dropdown list items are not consider as valid items...